# form controls are hidden when adding form tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

So, I'm having a little issue here with angular and forms

I'm creating a dynamic form, and it works correctly, but I needed to add some validations.

So I started to follow [this guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform) and I set it up correctly, but when I set the form tags to surround my form controls, I'm getting a blank form
[image]

[image]

But, if I comment the form tags, I get my form perfectly[image]

[image]

Any idea of why this is happening???

I have a couple of validation to show fields based on values, like[image]

custConfig is part of the scope, could the name of the form be interfering with the retrieval of the custConfig variable? and if its such, how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your using a repeater

```
ng-repeat="deliver in shipmentDetails"
```

Do you have anything in your object shipmentDetails array? if not then the form will not show anything

Comment: actually, it does have. I already found the solution. the form name and the array had the same name. For some reason, the answer that made me realize this disappeared, but I already solved it. thanks